# Displaying information on page by using parser

Tags: visualforce

I am unable to view the output onscreen unable to understand where i went wrong

```
public class JCSDeserialize {
public CaseStudyInvoiceWrapper wrapper {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public void deserialize() {
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndPoint('https://docsample.herokuapp.com/jsonSample');
        request.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
        request.setMethod('GET');

        HttpResponse response = h.send(request);

        wrapper = (CaseStudyInvoiceWrapper) JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(), CaseStudyInvoiceWrapper.class);
    }
}
```

My VFCode is as below

```
<apex:page controller="JCSDeserialize">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="JSON Deserialize Response">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="submit" action="{!deserialize}" reRender="CaseStudyinvoiceBlock"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="invoiceBlock" columns="1">
                <apex:repeat value="{!wrapper.CaseStudyinvoiceList}" var="CaseStudyinvoice">
                    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
                        <apex:facet name="header">CaseStudy {!CaseStudyinvoice.numberOfElements}</apex:facet>
                        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                            <apex:outputLabel value="No Of Records" for="numberOfElements" />
                            <apex:outputText value="{!CaseStudyinvoice.numberOfElements}" id="numberOfElements" />
                        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                        <apex:facet name="header">Invoice {!CaseStudyinvoice.numberOfElements} Items</apex:facet>
                        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!CaseStudyinvoice.lineItems}" var="item" id="lineItems">
                        <apex:column value="{!item.indication}" headerValue="Product Name"/>
                        </apex:pageBlockTable>
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                </apex:repeat>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock> 
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

My JSON Class

```
public class CaseStudyInvoiceWrapper {
 public class LineItem {
           public Integer totalPages {get;set;} 
           public Integer totalElements {get;set;} 
           public Boolean last {get;set;} 
           public Integer size {get;set;} 
           public Integer number_Z {get;set;} // in json: number
           public Integer numberOfElements {get;set;} 
           public Boolean first {get;set;} 
           public Boolean empty {get;set;} 
           public String title {get;set;} 
           public String studyName {get;set;} 
           public String description {get;set;} 
           public String phase {get;set;} 
           public String protocolId {get;set;} 
           public String indication {get;set;} 
           public String assetId {get;set;} 
           public String studyStatus {get;set;} 
           public String tenantId {get;set;} 
    }

    public class CaseStudyInvoice {
        public List<LineItem> lineItems {get; set;}
        public Integer numberOfElements {get; set;}
    }

    public List<CaseStudyInvoice> CaseStudyinvoiceList {get; set;}
    public String studyInfoId {get;set;} 
        public String title {get;set;} 
        public String studyName {get;set;} 
        public String description {get;set;} 
        public String phase {get;set;} 
        public String protocolId {get;set;} 
        public String indication {get;set;} 
        public String assetId {get;set;} 
        public String studyStatus {get;set;} 
        public String tenantId {get;set;} 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `rerender` doesn't work because its target id doesn't exist:

```
<apex:commandButton value="submit" action="{!deserialize}" reRender="CaseStudyinvoiceBlock"/>
```

Make sure to assign this id to your enclosing `<apex:pageBlock>` to see the contents of your page refresh after running the action `{! deserialize }`.